# ajax и запись в БД

Tags: ajax, база-данных

Всем привет!

Мб кто-нить поможет, а то у самого не получается(

Проблема в том, что запись в БД происходит, а сообщение об этом не возникает.

Вот html + js:

```
    <div class="add call block shadow">
    <form id="add-form" class="add-form" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="auto">Ваш номер телефона: </td>
                <td><input name="phone" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ваше имя и удобное время: </td>
                <td><input name="name_time" required></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="extra">
        <button id="add-button" class="add-button" name="request">Заказать звонок</button>
    </form>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#add-button').click(function () {
            $.post('/php_backend/back_call.php', $('#add-form').serialize(), function (data) {
                alert(data); 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Файл php:

```
    <?php

if ($_POST['extra'] == "" and $_POST['phone'] != "" and $_POST['name_time'] != "") {

    require_once '../config.php';


    $mysqli = new mysqli(Config::$db_host, Config::$db_user, Config::$db_pass, Config::$db_name);

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO back_call(phone,name_time,date) VALUES (?,?,NOW())");

    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $phone, $name_time);

    $phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $name_time = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name_time']);

    switch ($stmt->execute()) {
        case true:
            echo 1;
            break;
        case false:
            echo 0;
            break;
        default:
            echo 0;
    }
} else {
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

0 выводит без проблем в случае ошибки.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `execute()` Возвращает **TRUE** в случае успешного завершения или **FALSE** в случае возникновения ошибки.
Есть смысл заменить Ваш `switch` на условие

Comment: 0 и будет выводится без проблем, так как Вы не видите что не так при записи в базу. попробуйте выполнить вручную запрос с полученными данными, ознакомится с логами или же вывести что возвратить  $stmt->error в случае ошибки. Чтобы понять что не так

Comment: пробовал заменить switch на if -безрезультатно.

воспользовался вашим советом, насчет $stmt->error, но в эту ветку он не заходит т.к. запись в БД добавляется, а сообщение не выводится:

if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo $stmt->error;
    }

Comment: замена switch на if не решит вашу проблему, switch тут напросто не нужен

Answer (score 1):

замените часть со `switch` на другую конструкцию. например

```
if($stmt->execute()) {
echo 'ОК';
} else {
printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
}
```

Comment: Попробовал... ничего не выводит, а запись в БД происходит

Comment: если запись проходит, следовательно `$stmt->execute()` выполнился удачно и вернулся **true**